Trying to expose the whole appmodule of the mfe, but also at the same time trying to expose a specific component of that mfe, in angular
Trying to expose the whole appmodule of the mfe, but also at the same time trying to expose a specific component of that mfe, in angular. is this even possible? i have read the modulefederation documentation but till now all my attempts have not been succesful.
mfe1 exposure file webpack
module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({

  name: 'mfe1',

  exposes: {
      './web-components': './src/bootstrap.ts', // bootstrap --> main --> AppModule --> WebComp
      './warehouse-module': './src/app/components/menus/warehouse/warehouse.module.ts',
  },
  shared:
      // shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: "auto" }),
      share({
          "@angular/core": {
              requiredVersion: deps["@angular/core"]
          },
          "@angular/common": {
              requiredVersion: deps["@angular/common"]
          },
          "@angular/router": {
              requiredVersion: deps["@angular/router"]
          }

shell approuting file
// Redirect empty path to '/notfound'
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'notfound' },
// Redirect signed-in user to the '/example'
//
// After the user signs in, the sign-in page will redirect the user to the 'signed-in-redirect'
// path. Below is another redirection for that path to redirect the user to the desired
// location. This is a small convenience to keep all main routes together here on this file.
// { path: 'signed-in-redirect', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'notfound' },

// Auth routes for guests
{
    path: '',
    canMatch: [NoAuthGuard],
    component: LayoutComponent,
    data: {
        layout: 'empty'
    },
    children: [
        { path: 'confirmation-required', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/confirmation-required/confirmation-required.module').then(m => m.AuthConfirmationRequiredModule) },
        { path: 'forgot-password', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/forgot-password/forgot-password.module').then(m => m.AuthForgotPasswordModule) },
        { path: 'reset-password', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/reset-password/reset-password.module').then(m => m.AuthResetPasswordModule) },
        { path: 'sign-in', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-in/sign-in.module').then(m => m.AuthSignInModule) },
        { path: 'email-verify', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/email-verify/email-verify.module').then(m => m.EmailVerifyModule) },
        { path: 'sign-up', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-up/sign-up.module').then(m => m.AuthSignUpModule) }
    ]
},

// Auth routes for authenticated users
{
    path: '',
    canMatch: [AuthGuard],
    component: LayoutComponent,
    data: {
        layout: 'empty'
    },
    children: [
        { path: 'sign-out', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-out/sign-out.module').then(m => m.AuthSignOutModule) },
        { path: 'unlock-session', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/unlock-session/unlock-session.module').then(m => m.AuthUnlockSessionModule) },
        //u regjistrua ketu pasi se njihte si path
        // { path: 'email-verify', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/email-verify/email-verify.module').then(m => m.EmailVerifyModule) },
    ]
},

// Landing routes
{
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    data: {
        layout: 'empty'
    },
    children: [
        { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/landing/home/home.module').then(m => m.LandingHomeModule) },
    ]
},

// Admin routes
//ROUTES PASI JE LOGUAR NE APP
{
    path: '',
    canMatch: [AuthGuard],
    component: LayoutComponent,
    resolve: {
        initialData: InitialDataResolver,
    },
    children: [
        //default
        { path: 'example', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/admin/example/example.module').then(m => m.ExampleModule) },
        //not found
        { path: 'notfound', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/notfound/notfound.module').then(m => m.NotfoundModule) },
        //cannot load module
        { path: 'server-error', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/servererror/servererror.module').then(m => m.ServererrorModule) },
        // moduli i bere share
        // {
        //     path: 'magazina', //pathi duhet unik per app qe do bejme share
        //     loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule({
        //         type: 'module',
        //         remoteEntry: environment.mfe1,
        //         exposedModule: './warehouse-module'
        //     }).then(m => m.WarehouseModule).catch(err => { console.log('Oh no error lidhja me magazina!', err) })
        // },
        { matcher: startsWith('dashboard'), component: WrapperComponent, data: { importName: 'mfe1', elementName: 'mfe1-element' } },
        { matcher: startsWith('magazina'), component: WrapperComponent, data: { importName: 'mfe3', elementName: 'mfe1-element' } },

        { matcher: startsWith('crm'), component: WrapperComponent, data: { importName: 'mfe2', elementName: 'mfe2-element' } },            
        //route i bere share
        { path: 'programmatic', component: ExampleComponent},

        // Redirect wildcard to '/notfound' TODO mund te lihet nje tjeter me vone
        { path: '**',redirectTo: 'dashboard' }
    ]
}

